# Getting ant build error "Unable to locate specified base class 'mx.core.Application' for component

Tags: apache-flex, ant, flex4, flex3

I am trying to build using ant a Flex 3.5 app, and I keep on getting the error:
Unable to locate specified base class 'mx.core.Application' for component class 'main'.

my build.xml file looks something like:

```
<project name="ASC App" default="compile flex project">

<!-- load previously defined configuration properties file -->
<property file="build.properties" />

<!-- points to our flexTasks.jar we copied to the libs folder to distribute with the project -->
<taskdef resource="flexTasks.tasks" classpath="${basedir}/libs/flexTasks.jar"/> 

<!-- delete and create the DEPLOY dir again -->
<target name="init">
  <delete dir="${DEPLOY_DIR}" />
  <mkdir dir="${DEPLOY_DIR}" />       
</target>

<!-- Build and output the Main.swf-->
<target name="compile flex project" depends="init">
  <mxmlc file="src/main.mxml" output="${DEPLOY_DIR}/main.swf">
     <load-config filename="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks/flex-config.xml"/>
     <source-path path-element="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks"/>
     <source-path path-element="${APP_COMMON}"/>
     <source-path path-element="${FLEX_COMMON}"/>
<library-path dir="${LIBS_DIR}/AlivePDF/" append="true"/>
<library-path dir="${LIBS_DIR}" append="true"/>
     <compiler.debug>false</compiler.debug>    
  </mxmlc>
</target>
```

and my build.properties:

```
# Application name
APP_NAME=AS App

# SWF file
APP=main

# Common library
APP_COMMON=../ASC_common
FLEX_COMMON=../common
ALIVE_PDF=../libraries/AlivePDF/SWC/AlivePDF

# change this to your Flex SDK directory path
FLEX_HOME=/SDKs/flex_sdk_3_4

# this points to your project's src directory
SRC_DIR =${basedir}/src

# points to the project's libs directory
LIBS_DIR =${basedir}/libs

# this is the folder we want to publish the swf to
DEPLOY_DIR = ${basedir}/DEPLOY
```

Your help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to build using ant a Flex 3.5 app

Yet you have
FLEX_HOME=/SDKs/flex_sdk_3_4

Comment: Sorry i meant 3.4 but tried with 3.5 and other version as well so it cant be that